# view_as_windows on 4d array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

Given an ndarray of shape (batch_size, w, h, c), and a patch size (p, p), I want to extract patches from each 3D matrix (i.e. shape (p, p, c). No patches will overlap, so the stride can be thought of as p.

This should return an array with (batch_size * p * p, p, p, c)

Using  [skimage.view_as_windows](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) here is a minimal example

```
import numpy as np
import skimage

a = np.arange(8*8*2).reshape((8, 8, 2))
b = a * 2
c = np.concatenate((a[np.newaxis, :, :, :], b[np.newaxis, :, :, :]), axis = 0)
d = skimage.util.view_as_windows(c, 2, step  = 2).reshape((8*2*2, 2, 2, 2))
```

However, only the alternate values are what I expect:

```
d[0]
Out[183]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3]],
       [[16, 17],
        [18, 19]]])
d[1]
Out[184]: 
array([[[ 0,  2],
        [ 4,  6]],
       [[32, 34],
        [36, 38]]])
d[2]
Out[185]: 
array([[[ 4,  5],
        [ 6,  7]],
       [[20, 21],
        [22, 23]]])
d[3]
Out[186]: 
array([[[ 8, 10],
        [12, 14]],
       [[40, 42],
        [44, 46]]])
d[4]
Out[187]: 
array([[[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],
       [[24, 25],
        [26, 27]]])
```

Thus, `d[::2]` is close to my solution but half the values are lost

I am not sure if the problem is the window size or the step, or even if my problem is possible using `view_as_windows`, so I am open to any efficient suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you mean to return a volume of shape `(batch_size * w/p * h/p, p, p, c)`? i.e., if the patches are non-overlapping, then the product of the dimensions should be the same pre- and post-patching.

Having gotten that out of the way, here's my attempt. I'm changing the batch size and channel dimensions to make it clearer which is which.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage import util
batch = np.arange(4*8*8*3).reshape((4, 8, 8, 3))
blocked = util.view_as_blocks((1, 2, 2, 3))
patches = blocked.reshape((64, 2, 2, 3))
print(patches[0].transpose((2, 0, 1)))
print(patches[1].transpose((2, 0, 1)))
```

which gives:

```
[[[0 1]
  [8 9]]

 [[0 1]
  [8 9]]

 [[0 1]
  [8 9]]]
```

and

```
[[[ 2  3]
  [10 11]]

 [[ 2  3]
  [10 11]]

 [[ 2  3]
  [10 11]]]
```

Unfortunately, the reshape triggers a copy. I'm not sure whether there is a way to avoid it, but hopefully this is not your main computational/memory concern.